# Google App Script to look for an HTML tag using ID

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am using Google App Script to parse an HTML string, I need to look for a tag with particular id value.

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = 'http://www.cookcountypropertyinfo.com/pinresults.aspx'; 
    var payload = {
        '__LASTFOCUS': '',
      '__EVENTTARGET': '',
      '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'btnPIN',
      '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'CA0B0334',
      '__PREVIOUSPAGE': '0rEDfmpDJQHxEhK3Dp7ZzCXB7NF7NdGmDSIoxFE5z42EHh8NsVQxgH_JinuPWkplhkow1ZXvUdtcPISJkds36g2',
      '__EVENTVALIDATION': '+oXP/SPoa32228vqaMzj7w+0Cl3ZMxr3yZzo0Nbu/oqhqzpW5L67INJKcx5BkJDodz/7Sv/FTc7Hr0XC3RzC9Kppa1AnpwN1mnmFE8YD0/78p/uWZGee/1tAGm4B0Qbm9fuodpyQCVroRdgL9MEABHP0oeEPFJYFB5WTF5Wyyk/qB5olArp4I5L8QN0ylKOUpKDNoP36qAZTROlIDM/hLMPUsQJZmBF135VogZcsgzWeiRW+ZR0P4eJaHnDjvxHt0HrAS4pODE7H3bI8K0/VoDxxfd0JkQO7mEq4c3/J0UUf/vzN430Jd1oDKcJJ+7lqCqImhVOIckZBot7Y8mdYzkWhRVRqdpS/UaFxBvU0QLXTc+A+mnN8DmZMu2snN4vtC3P6rKDv7FYTgNg90uLf36FKw0VDaLZ1Of59IRrO74Vf9Kj0haY5xKKrVsxY3cga7qk9o4lJWe/PMaLCPkCOVihu0yGg/WHLGTZWZO88VzOB/YW+f0m8Ffk4LBuXx0w1ZxodV6299jrD4o9dtYtvRVH6UZH7+tZPKx6+2ZW3Bv6ZviSZfNTLTF2GoPLAfmnBXvrhTgWaIKQcjLDLl/f4NYq2SRfkgIyucbiX3Ap7T0RKPtFidx1asAFbYR/qqOVS',
      'ctl00$PINAddressSearch2$pin2Box1': '',
      'ctl00$PINAddressSearch2$pin2Box2': '',
      'ctl00$PINAddressSearch2$pin2Box3': '',
      'ctl00$PINAddressSearch2$pin2Box4': '',
      'ctl00$PINAddressSearch2$pin2Box5': '',
      'ctl00$HiddenField1': '',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$searchToValidate': 'PIN',
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox1': 20,
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox2': 19,
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox3': 331,
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox4': 033,
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox5': 0000,
      'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$btnSearch': 'SEARCH' 
        } 
      var options = {method: "POST",
                      payload: payload
                  }   
      var htmlString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText(); 
      var fromText = '<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TaxYearInfo_propertyTaxCode">';
      var toText = '</span>';
      var value = Parser.data(htmlString).from(fromText).to(toText).build();
      Logger.log(value);
}
```

Variable 'html' could receive a very large string containing a html web page,  I need to look for the tag which id='ContentPlaceHolder1_TaxYearInfo_propertyTaxCode'. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: I think the XmlService was intended to be used but all to often it has trouble parsing the html because it can't be malformed in any way.  So we typical have to resort to standard string methods or regular expressions.  If you want an answer you will probably have to provide a good portion of the string so that we can see it.  It's just easier to do and most people,like me, wont' even attempt to help you if you can't supply it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the reason I did not provide a portion of the string is because Logger.log() function could not return all the test string, what it returned is something like this:  Logging output too large. Truncating output. 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 Cook County Property Tax Portal
</title>.........

Comment: I don't really know what all  your looking for but I would probably consider doing with a Chrome Snippet.  I can organize it to load into a  spreadsheet.  The cool thing about doing it that way is that the DOM is live and you can use CSS selector to find everything you need.